# Is there a memory-efficient way of inserting zero-columns and rows into a numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-3.6

I have a big (symmetric) numpy matrix `arr`. It is of shape `arr.shape = (50_000, 50_000)`. I want to insert some zero-rows/columns (in a symmetric way). Let's say the amount of rows / columns I want to insert is maybe `123`.

### Small Example

```
import numpy as np

# Create symmetric square matrix
size = 3
arr = np.array(list(range(size**2))).reshape(size, size)
arr = arr + arr.T

# insert zero columns
# Each "1" represents a column from the original matrix, e.g.
# the first 1 is the first column of arr, the second 1 the second column of arr
# and so on
insert_cols = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]

# insert the zero rows / columns
current_index = 0
for col in insert_cols:
    if col == 0:
        arr = np.insert(arr, current_index, 0, axis=0)
        arr = np.insert(arr, current_index, 0, axis=1)
    current_index += 1

print(arr)
```

If I understand [`np.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) correctly, then this code creates a copy of the array and copies the content all the time.

### Question

I thought maybe this might be simpler / more efficient with one of the [sparse matrix classes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html)? Is there another way to make this more efficient?

Comment: Is preallocating the whole array at some fixed size an option?

Comment: I already had a similar case and I spent few hours on this: in my understanding (that is quite basic, I will follow this post), there is no way to have an efficient insert with np.insert or np.concatenate. The best I found is to convert the array into a list, then insert what you need and then reconvert the list into an array.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Yes! Preallocating is for sure possible

Comment: Obviously the result has to be a new array (`resize` method is very limited in what is can do), and thus you have to copy all the values of the source over.  I wouldn't do an iterative `insert`; too many new arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `insert_cols`, we can do something like this -

```
n = len(insert_cols)
out = np.zeros((n,n),arr.dtype)
idx = np.flatnonzero(insert_cols)
out[np.ix_(idx,idx)] = arr # or out[idx[:,None],idx] = arr
```

Alternatively, use a boolean version for indexing. Hence -

```
insert_cols_bool = np.asarray(insert_cols, dtype=bool)
```

Then, use `insert_cols_bool` in place of `idx`.

---

#### Sparse-matrix

To be more memory-efficient, we can store the output as a sparse matrix -

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

l = len(idx)
r,c = np.broadcast_to(idx[:,None],(l,l)).ravel(),np.broadcast_to(idx,(l,l)).ravel()
out = coo_matrix((arr.ravel(), (r,c)), shape=(n,n))
```

Comment: This looks much nicer - that's cool already (+1). However, I'm not sure about the overhead of `out[np.ix_(idx, idx)] = arr`. Is it essentially running only once over the array?

Comment: @MartinThoma Well `np.ix_(idx, idx)` creates a 2D open grid and then indexes into `out` array and assign `arr` values into it in one step.